# Drag and Drop List Elements in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am making an online editing application. List items are created by clicking the button on the left navigation bar. I want to use the drag and drop events to move the list around the div but i cant get it to work. Error message is: appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <script>
     window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('newHead').addEventListener('click', addHeader);
        document.getElementById('newLi').addEventListener('click', addListElement);
     }
     const addHeader = function(){
        const newHeader = document.createElement('ul');
        newHeader.className = 'newUl';
        newHeader.textContent = 'header';
        newHeader.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
        newHeader.setAttribute('draggable', true);
        newHeader.id = 'Head';
        const ul = document.getElementById('bulletPoints');
        ul.appendChild(newHeader);
        newHeader.addEventListener('click', selectElement);
     }

     const addListElement = function(){
         if (selected != null){
             const newListElement = document.createElement('li');
             newListElement.className = 'newLi';
             newListElement.textContent = 'textContent';
             newListElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
             newListElement.setAttribute('draggable', true);
             selected.appendChild(newListElement);
             newListElement.addEventListener('click', selectElement);
             newListElement.addEventListener('dragstart', drag);
         }
     }
     let selected;
     const selectElement = function(e){
         selected = e.target;
     }

     const allowDrop = function(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
     }

     const drag = function(ev) {
         ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
     }

     const drop = function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault();
         let data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
         ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
     }
  </script>
  
</head>

<body>
<div id="inputArea">
  <div id="leftNav">
      <button type='newHead' id='newHead' class='inlineButton'>Header</button>
      <button type='newLi' id='newLi' class='inlineButton'>List</button>
  </div>
  <div id="bulletPoints" contenteditable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
     
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="javascripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does **selected** contains in the addListElement function ? and can you provide the code in the script.js , the above code does not run

Comment: i have made edits to the code

Comment: still it does not work, since **selected** is null, function **addListElement** never gets executed.

Comment: I have fixed the code, it works now

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the **drag** function, id is not exists in the target. 
But if you want to move the element around the div, the inbuilt drag and drop functions are not good option as it is allowed to drag and drop to the zones which are eligible to drag and drop.

checkout this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event - for drag and drop functionality.

If you want to move element within the div, you should try something like this - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Editor</title>
  <script>
     window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('newHead').addEventListener('click', addHeader);
        document.getElementById('newLi').addEventListener('click', addListElement);
     }
     const addHeader = function(){
        const newHeader = document.createElement('ul');
        newHeader.className = 'newUl';
        newHeader.textContent = 'header';
        newHeader.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
        newHeader.setAttribute('draggable', true);
        newHeader.id = 'Head';
        const ul = document.getElementById('bulletPoints');
        ul.appendChild(newHeader);
        newHeader.addEventListener('click', selectElement);
        newHeader.addEventListener('dragstart', drag);
     }

     const addListElement = function(){
         if (selected != null){
             const newListElement = document.createElement('li');
             newListElement.className = 'newLi';
             newListElement.textContent = 'textContent';
             newListElement.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
             newListElement.setAttribute('draggable', true);
             selected.appendChild(newListElement);
             newListElement.addEventListener('click', selectElement);
             newListElement.addEventListener('drag', drag);
         }
     }
     let selected, current;
     const selectElement = function(e){
         selected = e.target;
     }

     const allowDrop = function(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
     }

     const drag = function(ev) {
         
         let id = ev.target.id;
         
         if (!id) {
         
            if (ev.target.parentNode) {
             id = ev.target.parentNode.id;
            } else {
              //handle this case
            }
            
         }
         
         if (id)
         ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", id);
    
         current = ev.target;
     }

     const drop = function(ev){
         ev.preventDefault(); 
         let data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
         let node = document.getElementById(data);
         node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
         ev.target.appendChild(node);
         
         ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
     }
  </script>
  
</head>

<body>
<div id="inputArea">
  <div id="leftNav">
      <button type='newHead' id='newHead' class='inlineButton'>Header</button>
      <button type='newLi' id='newLi' class='inlineButton'>List</button>
  </div>
  <div id="bulletPoints" contenteditable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
     
  </div>
  <div id="bulletPoints1" contenteditable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
     
  </div>
</div>

  <script src="javascripts/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```